# Add a "not" filter on Dajngo admin

Tags: python, django, admin

So I have this model:

```
class Follower(models.Model):
   language = models.ManyToManyField(
        "instagram_data.Language", verbose_name=_("language_code_name"), blank=True)

class Language(models.Model):
    code_name = models.CharField(max_length=6,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True,
                                 unique=True,
                                 db_index=True,
                                 verbose_name='language_code_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code_name
```

So in my admin panel I uses:
('language__code_name', MultiSelectDropdownFilter),
[image]

which is nice.

But I also what to have "filter OUT checkbox for languages)

I want to have a "remove from results" if language in ['ar', 'bg'...]

What is the proper way ? without slowing down everything.

Comment: Any other answer ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can import `from django.contrib.admin.filters import SimpleListFilter` then you can implement like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.filters import SimpleListFilter

class NotLanguageListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Not Language'
    parameter_name = 'not_language'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        languages = Language.objects.all()
        language_codes = [language.code_name for language in languages]
        return [(code_name, _('Not %s' % code_name)) for code_name in language_codes]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.exclude(language__code_name__in=self.value())
        return queryset

class FollowerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('language__code_name', MultiSelectDropdownFilter),
        ('not_language', NotLanguageListFilter),
    )

admin.site.register(Follower, FollowerAdmin)
```

Comment: <class 'instagram_data.admin.FollowerAdmin'>: (admin.E115) The value of 'list_filter[13][1]' must inherit from 'FieldListFilter'.

Comment: also:
[(code_name, _('Not %s' % code_name)) for code_name in language_codes]